# Bakelite as data storage

Tags: hardware, storage

Was bakelite used for computer data storage like it was used for grammophone records? My brother says he remembers this but I cannot find it on Google.

Comment: Are you sure your brother was not teasing you?

Comment: Well somewhat obviously it could be as we had cheap flexi discs records stuck on magazine covers but I can't think of anything that used bakelite as a backing medium, so my answer would be no.

Comment: Bakelite was hardly ever used for grammophone records, typical media were shellac and vinyl. I never heard of a bakelite usage for computer data. From bakelite, you might be able to mass-produce copies of identical data streams, and I'd expect them to have lots of bit-errors, given the typical consistency of bakelite products. So a don't see a plausible use for data storage.

Comment: Big picture, records are a form of data storage. But they weren't made with bakelite.

Comment: Bakelite wasn't, but vinyl and plastic foil sheet records were sometimes used in the 70s and 80s to distribute software, using the same encoding that was also used with audio tapes.

Comment: You can make ROM with a diode matrix, and in pre-PCB days, you'd often assemble circuits on tag strips that had bakelite bases... so sure, you could have bakelite-backed ROMs :-)

Comment: This can give you some more details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEmMPOHEdE4

Comment: The "bakelite in electronics" era did not overlap with the "one person can own a computer" era, and I can't imagine bakelite storage being superior to oxide-coated magnetic tape, so if this ever happened, I would suppose it to have been a niche application in the '40s and '50s.

Comment: Is it possible that the brother is not terribly knowledgeable about different kinds of plastic and just said 'bakelite' meaning 'some kind of plastic'? I know people who aren't sure of the differences between e.g. nylon, vinyl, PVC, etc.

Comment: Not Bakelite, but you could buy computer programs on Vinyl records in the former GDR.

Comment: Also not Bakelite and no "data" (but rather audio: See "Assmann Universa" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJswPveBviA , for example). Not a lot of reasons why a similar concept couldn't have been used for data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think so, and I don't recall reading or hearing about any such data storage technology, although mechanical data storage (in its broadest sense) might have been done using Bakelite. For example, cam-actuated "programmers" that control electrical equipment may may have used Bakelite cams, and this could be considered to be a form of data storage. But for storing arbitrary data, Bakelite does not seem to be a suitable techology. One of the earliest forms of mechanical data storage was paper tape, which derived from telegraph (Telex) technology.

It is true that early gramophone records were made from Bakelite, but that was replaced by shellac, and then vinyl.

Comment: Are you certain that Bakelite was the _recording medium_ for old records, and not just a substrate onto which the medium (e.g., shellac) was coated? Not only is Bakelite quite hard, it also has a coarse flaky structure which becomes plainly visible if you break a piece off of it.

Comment: @SolomonSlow - is that true, though?  bakelite as used in electronics was [laminar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bakelite#Phenolic_sheet) in nature, but bakelite jewellery had a fine, high-sheen surface that might well have served as a recording medium, though I never heard of such.

Comment: @SolomonSlow It may have been used as a substrate. I know that during WWII, shellac was in short supply, and so substitutes were used. These records were prone to deteriorate and crumble.

Comment: OK, I read through the whole [Bakelite article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bakelite), and now I understand that the majority of larger "Bakelite" products actually were moulded from a mixture of Bakelite resin with a filler material such as; cotton, asbestos, sawdust, etc. Any texture that I might have seen after breaking some moulded piece of Bakelite would have been due to the filler material, and not an inherent property of the plastic itself.

Answer (score 1):

And people did use vinyl grammophone records to store computer programs (though more as a gimmick), see for example [here](https://popcultureretrorama.com/2019/11/25/35-years-later-a-commodore-64-program-was-found-on-this-1984-album/) about a Commodore 64 program hidden within Prodigal’s 1984 album entitled Electric Eye.

There also was the [Flexi-disc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexi_disc), a thin square of plastic with a program on it, which could be produced very cheap, and came as part of a computer magazine. But again, vinyl, not bakelite.